# How to print the nth term of a string using scanf function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, c-strings

The console will not do anything after the user has entered a string.

I have got the code to work using `char string="enteraword"` and taking out the whole `printf` and `scanf` function, however I need the code to work with a `scanf` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char* string;
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  scanf("%s", string);
  char c=string[1];
  printf("The second letter in %s is %c", string, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a pointer (`string`), but ***where does it point?*** C doesn't have any kind of dynamic arrays.

Comment: Change   char* string; to   char* string = malloc(10);

Comment: @xing, thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This code has undefined behavior, you're passing an uninitialized pointer to `scanf()`, asking it to store a string there.

Also, remember that `%s` will stop at whitespace, so it's very unclear what "terms" should mean here.

Try e.g.:

```
char string[1024];
if(scanf("%1023s", string) == 1 && string[0] != '\0')
{
  const char c = string[1];
  printf("The second letter of '%s' is '%c'\n", string, c);
}
```

Comment: @nicomp True, I reliazed that and edited. Even test-ran my code on ideone. Thanks.